# É possível combinar first:child com :hover?

Tags: css, css3

É possível usar essas duas *pseudo-classes* juntas?

Tenho um `<ul>` e quero que a primeira `<li>` ao passar o mouse tenha uma propriedade diferente. Imagino que seria algo do tipo:

```
ul li:hover:firt-child {
}
```

Já tentei dessa forma e de outras mas não deu certo. E também não achei nada na internet pra ajudar.

Answer (score 7):

É possível encadear ambos, mas primeiro tens que indicar o elemento `li:first-child` e só depois o evento `:hover`:

```css
li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>primeira</li>
  <li>segunda</li>
  <li>terceira</li>
</ul>
```

Tal e qual como fazes quando aplicas o `:hover` a um elemento, primeiro dizes qual é esse elemento e depois dizes que queres um `:hover` nele.

O `:first-child` faz parte da especificação do elemento, motivo o qual deverá vir antes do `:hover`.

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma também. Meu css está "nav ul.menu > li:first-child:hover {}" Se eu tiro o :hover as propriedades funcionam, mas se boto o hover, para e funcionar.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Na verdade eu precisava pegar o elemento a dentro da primeira li. Dei mole! Ficou o seguinte: "nav ul.menu li:first-child > a:hover" Obrigada!

Answer (score 6):

Sim, é possível, você pode fazer `li:first-child:hover`, exemplo:

```css
ul li:first-child:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Primeira</li>
  <li>Segunda</li>
  <li>Terceira</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Consegui resolver. Na verdade eu precisava pegar o elemento a dentro da primeira li. Dei mole! Ficou o seguinte: "nav ul.menu li:first-child > a:hover" Obrigada!